How to suppress on-board arcing
Now if you want to design a development board, you will use a voltage with an output of 3 volts to 3 thousand volts, how can you suppress the arc at the output end? At the same time, what should be paid attention to when designing and using PCB?

You typically don't want to just "suppress" an arc--you want to prevent it from the beginning. Show the design you have now, so we can provide some specific guidance. It will generally amount to increasing clearances and creepages, but in some cases there are additional possibilities (potting is a somewhat common solution, for instance, but renders your circuit nearly un-repairable). Also make sure you don't have any flux residue on the board.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Once you HAVE an arc, there tends to be easier for it to happen again. Say, because of a carbonized path or worse. Yes, you have to prevent it from happening in the first place.

Is this an on-board electrical hazard (as one answer seems to think), or a potential hazard of wiring downstream of the board in question?  In other words, are you asking about an arc-fault detector, in response to onboard or external arcing?  Or is this a design question of how to avoid it in the first place?

A good starting point would be IPC-A-610: Acceptability of Electronic Assemblies, specifically section 12 - High Voltage and the applicable minimum electrical clearance guidelines for whatever features are involved. The big picture is minimize or cover up sharp points, maintain adequate physical separation, and do not rely solely on coatings to prevent arcing. For the specifics you'll have to get the pub yourself.

Minimum electrical conductor spacing as a function of voltage is listed in the IPC-2221 generic standard on printed board design. For free, you can download the Saturn PCB Toolkit, which has the same tables. For example, for external uncoated (no solder mask) conductors on a PCB with a 3 kV voltage difference between them, the IPC standard recommends at least 15 mm spacing assuming the PCB will be used below an elevation of 3050 m:

Traces with polymer coating (solder mask) over them have a minimum spacing of 8.42 mm. The same standard lists pin spacing for components as a function of voltage.
For safety reasons, I'd put the PCB inside an enclosure (either a plastic box or an earth grounded metal box). Wire the PCB to a high voltage connector using components rated to at least 3 kV. If the current is low, high voltage connectors and wires aren't necessarily expensive.

Note that IPC-2221 recommendations are generally considered extremely conservative for voltages above about 1000 V; you can typically put traces a good bit closer together without problems. I believe there is a newer document that supersedes IPC-2221, but I don't recall its designation.
